# Categorized Style : showing all possible values, not just the ones in use

Tags: qgis, style

I am new to QGIS and experimenting before rolling this out to my colleagues.
I have a shapefile with some codes, and i have a csv with those codes and other information that i need.
I have joined them, and that works fine - BUT is there a way to stylize the shapefile so that only records present in the shapefile show up in the layer manager and legend?

At present, my shapefile is nicely coloured by "description" but the layer props shows every single code/description in the CSV, not just the ones in use in the shapefile. In ESRI (for example) it would only show records with non-null values - I only have 4 or 5 codes in the shapefile, and, i mean, some of the values listed i know are not even polygons! But they are displayed, because the csv file has them.